# How to find simple secured web services online?

Tags: web-services, uddi

I am trying to write a test code against some secured web service.

So, I've searched the web for some (https) web service to write the client against but didn't find.

I've looked in one or more UDDI but without any results.

Comment: define "secure". There's probably a dozen ways to "secure" a web service, each one requires a variety of techniques to access. Best person to ask? the service provider

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a bunch of Amazon Web Services ( http://aws.amazon.com ) have HTTPS endpoints. Also, you can try searching on http://www.programmableweb.com